# AWS S3 putObjectAsync PHP / Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I'm using AWS SDK s3 and Laravel for uploading files. When files are below 100 MB, I use `putObject` else using `putObjectAsync`. `putObjectAsync` returns a promise from `GuzzleHttp` and a status of "pending", but, for some reason, the file doesn't upload unless I'm using a `wait()`.

It is a problem since it should upload after promise in a while, but checking our s3 bucket, no object has been added/uploaded.

**I'm using this method below:**

```
$s3disk = Storage::disk('s3');

$s3Client = $s3disk->getDriver()->getAdapter()->getClient();

$uploader = $s3Client->putObjectAsync([
    "Bucket" => $bucket_name,
    "Key" => $file_name,
    "SourceFile" => $local_file_path,
]);
```

is there a way to check the status of the async object? is this process normal? how long should we wait for the promise to upload the object successfully?

Answer (score 0):

It seems like I have no other way to use Async in AWS SDK's `putObjectAsync` but to use `wait()`. I found my answer in this thread -> [I queued my file upload to s3](https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/laravel/should-i-queue-file-uploads?page=1).